# Translate function not changing the position of a button in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to change the position of a button on my React page, but the transform: translate function is not working. I've tried changing the position to absolute, static, fixed, but nothing moves the button.

CSS:

```
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-600x, 300x);
}
```

TSX:

```
      <div className="Transform">
            <button onClick={clickHandler}>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/zf3vqPf/imageedit-4-2431153664.png" alt = "Button_image" />
            </button>
        </div>
```

Other CSS is working, but translate is not.

Comment: you need to use 600px, not 600x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
transform: translate(-600x, 300x);
```

Use px , em , rem etc as X is not a unit

```
transform: translate(-600px , 300px);
```